# Row sum of positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

I have the following positive definite matrix :

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \alpha_2 & ... & \alpha_n \\
\alpha_1 & 1 & ... & \alpha_n \\
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & 1... & \alpha_n \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & ... & 1 
\end{bmatrix}

with $\alpha_i \in ]0,1[$ for all $i$.

Let $M$ be the inverse of that matrix. Since the matrix is pos. def. we know that $m_{ii} > 1$ for all $i$ and we can also show that all the other terms $m_{ij}$ with $i\neq j$ are negative.

I would like to show that $\sum_j m_{ij} > 0$ for all $i$.

Any idea ? Thanks

**Edit:** Found a proof, I'll share it if anyone's interested.